# Why does << operator not work on derived class from ofstream?

Tags: c++

First I see a many posts that say deriving a class from `ostream` is non-trivial but then that's understandable as well since the 'ostream` itself requires a furnishing a buffer to the stream.

What about deriving from `fstream` or `ofstream`? I think this should be straightforward because these base classes do have their buffers setup and deriving from them merely instantiate `fstream` and thus encapsulating it.

Now I am creating a log file which looks like this (header file)

```
class lfstream : public std::ofstream
{
public:
    lfstream();
    ~lfstream();

    void log(const std::string &text);

protected:
    std::ofstream logfile;
    char logfname[32];
};

extern lfstream ls;
```

The corresponding cpp files is

```
lfstream ls; // global object of log file so I can write to it

lfstream::lfstream() : logfname("Mylog.txt")
{
    logfile.open(logfname, std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::app);
}

lfstream::~lfstream()
{
}

void lfstream::log(const std::string &text)
{
    logfile << text;
}
```

Now in main() function

```
int main(int argc, char * argv)
{
    // this is for camparison, << operator works on ofstream
    std::ofstream stockstream("ostream_test.txt");
    stockstream << "<< test ostream" << std::endl; // works

    // But << doesn't work on my derived class which is also a stream
    ls << "<< test ls stream"; // why this doesn't go into the file?
    ls.log("This works"); // but this does
}
```

So my first question is, is deriving from `ostream`like above Okay? Secondly, why does the `<<` doesn't work on the derived class?

**Update**

So my implementation was wrong. I eleminated the member variable `ofstream` object now the constructor becomes like this:

```
lfstream::lfstream() : logfname("debug_log.txt"), std::ofstream(logfname )
{
}
```

But how do I implement the log() function now?

**Update 2**

My log does print more data in actuality and formats it accordingly. This is the reason I am not instantiating just `ofstream`

```
void lfstream::log(const std::string &text)
{
    const time_t ctt = time(0);
    int threadID = GetCurrentThreadId();

    logfile << std::setw(40) << std::left << text << " thread id = " << threadID << "\t" << asctime(localtime(&ctt)); // << std::endl;
}
```

This means I can call `ls.log(...)` and it does the formating.

Comment: Apart from anything else, you are both deriving from ofstream _and_ having a protected ofstream member.

Comment: And your log function writes to the member (which has been opened) and operator << writes to the base which was not opened

Comment: @NeilButterworth good point! That does't look right.let me look back at my code.thanks

Comment: even if it was ok, why do you want to inherit? Just remove the inheritance, write an `operator<<` and use the member (that is already there)

Comment: @tobi303 because my log actually has more to it, I pass more parameters and it formats them all and also prints the thread id as well. That is the reason for derivation so I do all this in one function.

Comment: I cannot follow you, you can do all that also if the `ofstream` is a member

Comment: let me ask differently. Do you really want your logfile to be an `ofstream`? Does your logfile really need for example a public  `seekp` method? (and I wont buy the argument that it doesnt hurt if the methods are there but you dont use them, because it does hurt)

Comment: @tobi303 I did update 2 on post, see the reason. if I instantiate only `ofstream myfile`, I can expect it to write complex data to file and format it like I want it to format like in `myfile.log()`. I have to type formatting every time!

Comment: ...and? you can write exactly that code for the `log` method without inheriting from `ofstream`. Actually if you do inherit the code doesnt make sense, because you still write to `logfile` which is a member

Comment: @tobi303 but I thought that would be rather C style than having a log object. I will likely add more log methods too which outputs different kind of data but format it consistently.

Comment: I have the feeling that you misunderstand the usefulness of inheritance. Inheritance by itself isnt something positive that makes your code more c++-ish. I was also thaught at school that writing c++ == inheriting, but this cannot be more wrong. It took me many years to realize that. Let me asure you that you dont need to inherit from anything here. Just keep the member that you already have and write to it (just like you do it in that `log` method) and remove the inheritance

Comment: @tobi303 I hear you, so you are suggestion composition over inheritance in this case. That does make sense and it may be a better solution than inheritance in this case, need to refresh some theory i guess. But I guess I was a little greedy too, wanting to use both << and my log() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am posting the answer. My original code was flawed as I was using both composition and inheritance at the same time (thanks to the comments for pointing this out). Both methods provide a different form of solution, so first is to decide which one to use.

**Composition**

My class was declaring `std::ofstream logfile;` so I didn't have to derive from `ofstream` just delegate the work to its member variable. This is composition.

**Inheritance**

Since my class was deriving from `std::ofstream`, I didn't have to declare the same member variable. With that removed, the class looks like following now. The idea is to mimic `ofstream`, implement same constructors and instantiate the base `ofstream` class in them (I have implemented only one constructor).

```
lfstream::lfstream(const std::string& logfilename) : _logfname(logfilename),
        std::ofstream(logfilename)
{
}

lfstream::~lfstream()
{
}

void lfstream::log(const std::string &text)
{
    *this << text;
}
```

This does fix the original problem and now `<<` works on my derived class.

Comment: if you think the answer solved your problem you can accept it ;)